# Jquery Show Hide Shows When Clicking On Other Visible Page Links

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I am using the jquery show hide div on a wordpress blog.

link available here   72.52.206.17/ ~guerilla/ category/vlog/   <-remove extra spaces un url

code for jquery is pulled in the header php like so:

```
<!-- VLOG EXPANDABLE BOX -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content1').hide();

  $('a').click(function(){
 $('.content1').show('slow');

});

 $('a.close').click(function(){
        $('.content1').hide('slow');
})

});
</script>

<!-- VLOG EXPANDABLE BOX -->
```

then we have code that shows and hides the menu blog roll on a special page called category-vlog php:

code is as such:

```
<a href="#" id="click">Expand Blog</a>
     <div class="content1">
          <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            <p> <a href="#" class="close">Collapse Blog</a></p>
</div>
```

- this code in itself functions perfectly- what happens when you click on the main menu links is that the hidden div appears, how do I get the div to stay hidden when I click on other page links?

Im at a loss.

- even though this is a minor issue- its major in the site owners mind- how do I get to

---

I'm still missing something, I made the changes suggested by Robotsushi, however I am not able to make this work.

When I make changes to the code in the proper places the show/hide stops working.

Comment: Since I can't edit this for some reason, do you mind wrapping your code around the `{}` tags?

Comment: not sure what you mean? can you give me an example?

Comment: Nvm, Tom Walters already edited for you :D (you see the gray background surrounding your code?)

Comment: didnt work with his edits- still does the same thing-  there has to be a way of isolating the whole div or calling the show hide a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off switch your approach to use the `toggle` jQuery method. It encapsulates what you are trying to accomplish. so you can say:

```
$(".content1").toggle();
```

This will change the display property to the opposite of its current state. 
If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.

This code is the problem:

```
$('a').click(function(){
 $('.content1').show('slow');
```

What this is saying is: every time an  element is clicked go ahead and open the element with a class name of "content1".

Change the a to the id or class name of the element you want to open content1 with. Something like this:

```
$('#OpenContent1').click(function(){
     $('.content1').show('slow');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply-  I changed to .toggle and re uploaded the header.php but- maybe Im still missing something because the same result still happens-  div shows when clicking on the main nav links.

Comment: Im not sure how I would specify only content1 to open?  I thought that was what I was doing?

Comment: Ken White- "Im sure this is breaking some sort of rule- but when i signed up I cannot post questions to this thread from another computer"

Comment: Did this solve your issue if so please mark it as anwsered if not please specify what is not answered  ?